# How to repartition Spark DStream Kafka ConsumerRecord RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I am getting uneven size of Kafka topics. We want to repartition the input RDD based on some logic.

But when I try to apply the repartition I am getting `object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord` error.

I found following workaround

[Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html)

Call `rdd.forEachPartition` and create the `NotSerializable` object in there like this:

```scala
rdd.forEachPartition(iter -> {
  NotSerializable notSerializable = new NotSerializable();

  // ...Now process iter
});
```

ABOVE LOGIC APPLIED HERE not sure if I missed anything

```scala
val stream =KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParam) ).map(_.value())
      stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        val repartitionRDD = flow.repartitionRDD(rdd,1)
        println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&& repartitionRDD " + repartitionRDD.count())
       val modifiedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions { 
          iter =>{
            val customerRecords: List[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = List[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]()
             while(iter.hasNext){
                  val consumerRecord :ConsumerRecord[String, String] = iter.next()
                  customerRecords:+ consumerRecord
             }
             customerRecords.iterator
          }
        }
        val r = modifiedRDD.repartition(1)
        println("************* after repartition " + r.count())
```

BUT still getting same object not Serializable error.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

1. I tried to make stream transient but that did not resolve the issue either.
2. I made the test class as Serializable but did not fix the issue.